# i have obtained the dictionary from json response and now i want to add this dictionary to my existing plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

i have obtained a jason response and it is further stored in a dictionary now i want to add this dictionary t my plist ,so that the plist can take values against entries from json response .how should i do it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString* myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];

[myDictionary writeToFile:myPath atomically:YES];
```

In your case you already have the myDictionary, so try a writeToFile and add the path to the file you would like to write to.